# Detect underscore from a particular word of a UITextView's text

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to detect "_" from a particular word of a UITextView's text.
I already tried this : 

But this calculates the range of first underscore only.

> ```
> NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textView.text];
> NSRange range=[textView.text rangeOfString:@"_"];
> [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:range];
> textView.attributedText=string;
> ```

My output is coming like this

> Tadeusz_Kościuszko was a military leader who became a national hero in
>   Poland. A poster for the Paris premiere of Jules_Massenet's 1910 opera
>   Don_Quichotte.

And I want something like this:

> Tadeusz Kościuszko was a military leader who became a national hero in
>   Poland. A poster for the Paris premiere of Jules Massenet's 1910 opera
>   Don Quichotte.

Also I want to clear color the underscores just from the names. Not from the other text of UITextView.

I dont want to remove it from the whole text of UITextView but just from the particular words.
Anyone having suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Would you please add an example input text and the expected result text?

Comment: Do you know the exact words that either should _have_ underscore or the exact ones that should _not_ have underscore?

Answer (score 4):

```
textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textView.text];


NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(_)" options:kNilOptions error:nil];


NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,string.length);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:subStringRange];
}];

textView.attributedText=string;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"This_is_a_string";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_"
                                     withString:@" "];

// str = "This is a string"
```

More on [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW25)

Comment: I can't do this as I need to have space between first name and second name. Its better I just put clear color on uderscores.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
NSString *str   =   @"Tadeusz_Kościuszko was a military leader who became a national hero in Poland. A poster for the Paris premiere of Jules_Massenet's 1910 opera Don_Quichotte.";
    NSString *newStr    =   [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"NEW STR ::::: %@",newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the workaround :)

> NSString *strTemp = textView.text;
>
> ```
> NSMutableAttributedString *mutString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:strTemp];
> NSString *substring = @"_";
>
> NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0,mutString.length);
>
> NSRange wholeTextRange = [strTemp rangeOfString:strTemp];
>
> [mutString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:wholeTextRange];
>
> NSRange foundRange;
>
> while (searchRange.location < mutString.length)
> {
>     searchRange.length = mutString.length-searchRange.location;
>
>     foundRange = [strTemp rangeOfString:substring options:nil range:searchRange];
>
>     if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound) {
>         // found an occurrence of the substring! do stuff here
>         [mutString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:foundRange];
>
>         searchRange.location = foundRange.location+foundRange.length;
>     } else {
>         // no more substring to find
>
>         [txtComment setAttributedText:mutString];
>
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to selectively remove underscores you need to know the *range of text from which you want to remove them.*

Then you can use a regular expression to get an array of ranges which match the underscore in that known range.

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex =  [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"_" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matchingRangesInSelectedRange = [regex matchesInString:yourString options:0 range:knownRangeToCheckForMatches];
```

You can then iterate over the ranges in the array and do whatever changes you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which strings should not be cleaned or which that should *not* be cleaned you could do something like this:

```
NSString *stringWithUnderScore = @"A rather long text with some_odd_underscores but also names like André_Franquin & Albert_Uderzo";
NSSet *stringsThatShouldKeepUnderscore = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"some_odd_underscores", nil];
NSArray *singleStrings = [stringWithUnderScore componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableString *newCompleteString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSString *singleString in singleStrings) {
        if (![stringsThatShouldKeepUnderscore containsObject:singleString]){
            NSString *fixedString = [singleString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
            [newCompleteString appendString: fixedString];
        } else{
            [newCompleteString appendString:singleString];
        }
        [newCompleteString appendString:@" "];
    }

NSLog(@"new string:%@",newCompleteString);
```

Edit: If you do *not* have this information you could try to make some kind of parser checking if each of the strings separated by "_" have capital-letters, indicating a name. Not fail-safe, but without knowledge about the text I can't really see any better option.